# Taylor expansion for $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ centered at $a=16$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Go ahead, write out what you want, compute derivarives, the works. You are supposed to learn something by doing this, you know...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let $z:=x-16$, then this is the same as $\sqrt{16+z}$ at $z=0$. Use the binomial series:
$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom\alpha n x^n$$
Now we have 
$$(16+z)^{1/2}=4\cdot\left(1+\frac z{16}\right)^{1/2}=\\
=4\cdot\sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{1/2}n\frac{z^n}{16^n}\,.$$

Comment: Can you explain why z = x-16 is the same as sqrt(16 + z) at z=0 ?

Comment: I mean, $f(x)=\sqrt x=\sqrt{16+z}$ as the function in $z=(x-16)$.

Comment: This is the way I would do it. (+1) If this were on a homework for Taylor series, however, I would do it the more formulaic way (taking derivatives at $a=16$, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way? Perhaps, [Taylor expansion for f(x) = sqrt(x) centered at a=16](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor%20expansion%20for%20f%28x%29%20=%20sqrt%28x%29%20centered%20at%20a=16).

Comment: This may be slightly misleading: this "simplest way", besides not contributing a lot to some newbie's understanding, would hardly be acceptable in any more or less decent college/university, so it may not be the wisest thing to do (for the student, of course).

Comment: @DonAntonio Honestly, the question is so ridiculous, that it's hard to give a serious answer. As a college professor, I'd certainly expect even an average student to be able to do this with modest effort. Also as a college professor, I tell students to use all kinds of tools to understand things and I think that WolframAlpha is a bit under-utilized, as illustrated by the fact that I typed his *exact* title into WolframAlpha.

Comment: Is this answer any worse than the fully worked out solutions to elementary HW questions that we see on this site all the time? This is a serious question. I honestly dont' know how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Well @Mark: even full-worked solution leave a little window of hope for the student to understand a little: (s)he has to copy the question and, hopefully, understand it. WA doesn't care, and cannot either, about this. I also think this is a lame question from a college and up student, but...

Comment: @Mark: I don’t downvote, but in my opinion it is indeed much worse: it teaches no mathematics at all, and I can’t see it doing anything to increase anyone’s understanding of Taylor series. Nor do I think it legitimate to justify a shoddy answer by ridiculing the question. Your answer would have been reasonable as a mildly facetious comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I can assure you that my answer was neither facetious nor intended to ridicule. I believe that low effort questions *should* receive low effort answers, in part, because low effort questions fail to convey the context necessary to formulate a full response. To often, I've put effort into an answer only to have the OP say, "Well, I really meant...". I also genuinely believe that WA is an underutilized resource and one of the areas that I try to cover in my answers here is its *proper* use. Although, again, proper use requires effort.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott One other comment - it is clearly *not* the purpose of this site to *teach* mathematics. If it were, then fully worked out solutions 10 minutes after the question is asked (like the accepted answer to this question) would be excluded.

Comment: @Mark: In my view it *should* have been facetious, and I did not suggest that it was intended to ridicule the OP, just the question. And as I pointed out, you don’t know when it’s asked that this is a low-effort question. It is a perfectly reasonable question for someone who knows the textbook approach to ask: it’s not exactly unheard of in mathematics for there to be more than one approach, some easier than others. // If the point is understanding of Taylor series, this is obviously *not* a proper use of W|A.

Comment: @Mark: On the contrary, Berci’s answer is a *good* teaching answer: it shows an efficient way to calculate that Taylor series that is **not** the textbook approach.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hmm... The Binomial theorem certainly is in my textbook. :)  If Berci had *started* with "Hint: Look into the binomial theorem" and if his answer had then come about via some dialogue, then I could certainly agree with you. However, he simply typed out the correct a fully correct answer a scant 10 minutes after the question was posted. You can find any number of complaints about this approach to "teaching" on Meta, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9064/discussion-between-mark-mcclure-and-brian-m-scott)

Answer (score 6):

note that $f(x)=2^0x^{1/2}$, $f'(x)=-2^1 x^{-1/2}$, $f''(x)=\frac{2^2}{3} x^{-3/2}$,$f'''(x)=-\frac{2^3}{15}x^{-5/2}$ $\cdots$

Then just plug these into the normal formula for a taylor series expansion

[image: formla for taylor series]

here your  $a=16$. Then see what patterns you can find to write these in summation notation!

Comment: (+1) because this is the way it should be done on homework (which is my guess here). However, it is not what I would call "simpler"